# HasAlternateKey Allows Duplicate Entries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following defined in my `DbContext`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Order>().HasAlternateKey(o => o.OrderNumber);

    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

But when I insert a few orders, each time using this same code:

```
var order = new Order()
{
    OrderNumber = "12345",
    OrderParts = new List<OrderPartQuantity>()
    {
        new OrderPartQuantity()
        {
            Part = _context.Parts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.BellNumber == "100123"),
            Quantity = 10
        }
    }
};

_context.Orders.Add(Order);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

The order is inserted each time, even though they all have the same `OrderNumber` value.

Have I understood this incorrectly, or am I missing something? I'm struggling to find an explanation for this

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that calling `HasAlternateKey` in `OnModelBuilding` actually requires a new db migration before it is applied.

After calling

```
Add-Migration TestHasAlternateKeys
```

This migration was created

```
public partial class HasAlternateKeyTest : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "OrderNumber",
            table: "Orders",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddUniqueConstraint(
            name: "AK_Orders_OrderNumber",
            table: "Orders",
            column: "OrderNumber");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropUniqueConstraint(
            name: "AK_Orders_OrderNumber",
            table: "Orders");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "OrderNumber",
            table: "Orders",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(string));
    }
}
```

Now, after calling

```
Update-Database
```

I can no longer to duplicate that column